# uniqueness in two columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, ddl

Here is a simple data set about soccer : a table `team` and a table `match`

```
        Table « soccer.team »
┌─────────┬─────────┬───────────────┐
│ Column  │  Type   │ Modifiers     │
├─────────┼─────────┼───────────────┤
│ team_id │ integer │ not NULL      │
│ name    │ text    │ not NULL      │
│ code    │ text    │               │
└─────────┴─────────┴───────────────┘
Index:
    "team_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (team_id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "match" CONSTRAINT "match_foreign_team_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (foreign_team_id) REFERENCES team(team_id)
    TABLE "match" CONSTRAINT "match_home_team_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (home_team_id) REFERENCES team(team_id)

             Table « soccer.match »
┌────────────────────┬──────────┬───────────────┐
│      Column        │   Type   │ Modifiers     │
├────────────────────┼──────────┼───────────────┤
│ matchday           │ integer  │ not NULL      │
│ home_team_id       │ integer  │ not NULL      │
│ foreign_team_id    │ integer  │ not NULL      │
│ home_team_score    │ smallint │ not NULL      │
│ foreign_team_score │ smallint │ not NULL      │
└────────────────────┴──────────┴───────────────┘
Check constraints:
    "match_check" CHECK (home_team_id <> foreign_team_id)
    "match_foreign_team_score_check" CHECK (foreign_team_score >= 0)
    "match_home_team_score_check" CHECK (home_team_score >= 0)
Foreign keys:
    "match_foreign_team_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (foreign_team_id) REFERENCES team(team_id)
    "match_home_team_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (home_team_id) REFERENCES team(team_id)
```

Each team can play at most once per match day either receiving a foreign team or being a foreign team. There must be 2 teams and only 2 teams per match.
Is there a design that ensures a team plays at most once per matchday?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS intarray;
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS btree_gist;

alter table match add exclude using gist
  (
     matchday with =,
     (array[home_team_id,foreign_team_id]) with &&
  );
```

This will prevent from inserting a row with matching matchday and overlapping [home_team_id, foreign_team_id] arrays.

Comment: Great idea, but shouldn't this include`matchday  with =`? This is the first time I've heard mention of `EXCLUDE` constraints. Your answer would benefit greatly from an explanation what the constraint does.

Comment: Best answer. I am not sure the `intarray` extension is required since the `&&` operator seems to be present [by default](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-array.html#ARRAY-OPERATORS-TABLE)

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a unique constraint would fit the bill:

```
ALTER TABLE match ADD UNIQUE (matchday, home_team_id);
ALTER TABLE match ADD UNIQUE (matchday, foreign_team_id);
```

If a team can be home team *and* foreign team, things get more complicated, and you need these extensions:

```
CREATE EXTENSION intarray SCHEMA public;    -- for the "gist__int_ops" opclass
CREATE EXTENSION btree_gist SCHEMA public;  -- for the "gist_int4_ops" opclass
```

Then you can create an exclusion constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE soccer.match ADD EXCLUDE USING gist (
   matchday gist_int4_ops WITH OPERATOR(pg_catalog.=),
   (ARRAY[home_team_id, foreign_team_id]) gist__int_ops WITH OPERATOR(public.&&)
);
```

Basically, two rows are counted as “equal” if their `matchday`s are equal and the arrays formed by `home_team_id` and `foreign_team_id` have common elements.

Comment: This does not address the issue that the team then can play twice, once as home team and once as foreign team.

Comment: yes a team can be either `home` or `foreign` but not both for the same matchday. I am going to update my question to make that clearer.

Comment: An exclusion constraint can help. I'll come up with an example.

Comment: Ok, I have opdated the answer to cover the desired case.

Answer (score 2):

A team cannot play more than once per matchday, so have a table listing matchday and teams. Combined with a number for the match and an indicator for HOME or AWAY you'd have all data needed. For instance:

```
             Table « soccer.match »
+-----------------------------------------------+
¦      Column        ¦   Type   ¦ Modifiers     ¦
+--------------------+----------+---------------¦
¦ matchday           ¦ integer  ¦ not NULL      ¦
¦ matchnum           ¦ integer  ¦ not NULL      ¦
¦ team_id            ¦ integer  ¦ not NULL      ¦
¦ teamtype           ¦ varchar  ¦ not NULL      ¦
¦ score              ¦ smallint ¦ not NULL      ¦
+-----------------------------------------------+
Check constraints:
    "match_teamtype_check" CHECK (teamtype IN ('HOME','AWAY'))
    "match_score_check" CHECK (score >= 0)
Indexes:
    "match_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (matchday, match_no, team_id, teamtype)
    "match_team_once_per_day" UNIQUE KEY, btree (matchday, team_id)
    "match_two_teams_only" UNIQUE KEY, btree (matchday, matchnum, teamtype)
```

Comment: Same as below, how can we ensure there are no 3 opponents matchs?

Comment: As `matchday` + `match_no` + `team_id` +`teamtype` are unique (primary key) and there are only two values allowed for `teamtype` (check constraint), there can only be two opponents, not more. (However, it would be possible with this design to only enter one single team for a match instead of two.) The same is true for Adder's answer when you make `is_home_team` a boolean.

Comment: Not really because adding a row with two different teams for the same matchday & match_no & teamtype would not offend such index.

Comment: Oh, you are right. I even forgot the unique constraint to ensure a team can only play once in a day :-P I've added constraints to my answer now.

Comment: What is `matchnum`?

Comment: Some number you make up for a match. Same thing as Adder's `match_id`. I don't think you need a separate table for this, though, as long as don't want to store additional information (such as at what time the match took place or who was the referee).

Comment: I support this solution.

Comment: ok, I think I have enough material, thanks to you, to create the correct structure. I prefer using deferrable foreign keys instead of using triggers. Would you mind if I post the solution I ended up with?

Comment: Sure, your solution may help further readers. Please do post (and accept) it :-) And I am curious to see it, too.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a table like the following, you can place a unique constraint or multi-column primary key on `matchday` and `team_id`:

`team_match` table:

```
┌────────────────────┬──────────┬───────────────┐
│      Column        │   Type   │ Modifiers     │
├────────────────────┼──────────┼───────────────┤
│ matchday           │ integer  │ not NULL      │
│ team_id            │ integer  │ not NULL      │
│ is_home_team       │ integer  │ not NULL      │
│ match_id           │ integer  │ not NULL      │
│ score              │ integer  │ not NULL      │
└────────────────────┴──────────┴───────────────┘
```

`match` table:

```
┌────────────────────┬──────────┬───────────────┐
│      Column        │   Type   │ Modifiers     │
├────────────────────┼──────────┼───────────────┤
│ match_id           │ integer  │ not NULL      │
└────────────────────┴──────────┴───────────────┘
```

Comment: In this configuration it sounds it is possible to have a 3 opponents match. I am going to update my question about this point.

Comment: Oops, seems I was late with my answer, as my solution is about the same as the one suggested here. `is_home_team` should be boolean, not integer. Make `matchday` + `team_id` + `is_home_team` + `match_id` unique then and you're done.

Comment: No the unique constraint needs to be on matchday and team_id otherwise multiple matches a day would be possible.

Answer (score 0):

you can use two digit comparison trick here, like:

```
create unique index ui on soccer.match (matchday, greatest(home_team_id,foreign_team_id), least(home_team_id,foreign_team_id))
```

Comment: I don't think that's a solution, either.

Comment: This would allow a team to play several times, as long as the other team id changes.

Comment: In your unique index, you can have (1,2,1) but also (1,3,1) so team 1 would play more than once.

Comment: ah - get it now. thanks. so then @LaurenzAlbe proposed two UK would solve it

Answer (score 0):

Your table design looks fine. But you are right, it cannot guarantee that a team plays only once per matchday. You'd need another table for this. What you can do is add this other table to your already existing design and fill it with a trigger.

```
             Table « soccer.match_team »
+-----------------------------------------------+
¦      Column        ¦   Type   ¦ Modifiers     ¦
+--------------------+----------+---------------¦
¦ matchday           ¦ integer  ¦ not NULL      ¦
¦ team_id            ¦ integer  ¦ not NULL      ¦
+-----------------------------------------------+
Index:
    "match_team_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (matchday, team_id)
```

Now write a trigger that writes the two records whenever a `match` record gets written. (You may also want to code something for updates and deletes, if you want to allow for these.)